How to copy and paste in wpf richtextbox containing runs and inlineUICOntainer?
I have created a RichTextBox in wpf containing the below content
<RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox"
             IsDocumentEnabled="True"
             AutoWordSelection="True"
             IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled="True">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBlock Text="Sample"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>

What I want to achieve here is
1)Copy selected text from the RichTextBox and paste inside the same RichTextBox 
2)Copy selected text from one RichTextBox and paste into another RichTextBox in the same application
3)Copy selected text from the RichTextBox and into the clipboard as plaintext which can then be pasted into apps like notepad etc
Issue 1:
when i type any normal text and try copying the whole content in richtextbox, InlineUIContainer is not copied,
Issue 2:
When I want to select only few words in a whole sentence, containing a mix of Runs and InlineUIContainer , its the same.
What i have seen from other stack overflow answers on almost similar queries, that you iterate through the blocks, but it seems to not work, How do i even copy and paste
I understand, there is no direct approach and needs some looping through or working with the text pointers.
This is something i tried to format myself on CTRL+C
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Block block in RichTextBox.Document.Blocks)
{
    if (block is Paragraph p)
    {
        foreach (Inline inline in p.Inlines)
        {
            if (inline is Run run)
            {
                if (RichTextBox.Selection.Contains(run.ContentStart))
                {
                    sb.Append(run.Text);
                }
            }
            else if (inline is InlineUIContainer iuic)
            {
                if (RichTextBox.Selection.Contains(iuic.ContentStart))
                {
                    var tb = iuic.Child as TextBlock;
                    sb.Append(tb.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This above code detects the InlineUIContainer, but if i select some portion of text in Run,
ex :
<Run>This is example</Run>

If i select only "example", it will give me the whole Run "This is example" instead of just "example"

updated the copy paste use case in the question

It's not "copy and past"; it's "clone" (or parse). UI elements can only belong to one (part of the) visual tree at a time.

This answer is modified version of @BionicCode answer, and this answer exactly what was needed, beware, below code is not optimized
what we are doing here is

We are checking all the elements within the selected range
InlinUIContainer is checked if its Text Pointer is within the selection range
For normal Text, we iterate 1 character at a time until we reach end of selection or end of content or if next element is a InlinUIContainer.

if (richTextBox.Selection.IsEmpty) return;
    
var parsingInProgress   = true;
var selectedTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    
TextPointer currentStartPosition = richTextBox.Selection.Start;
TextPointerContext context       = currentStartPosition.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
Paragraph paragraph              = currentStartPosition.Paragraph;
    
while (context != TextPointerContext.None)
{
    // Append a line break if we are in the scope of a new Paragraph
    if (currentStartPosition.Paragraph != paragraph)
    {
        _ = selectedTextBuilder.AppendLine();
    }
    
    var text = string.Empty;
    switch (context)
    {
        case TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement:
        {
            if (richTextBox.Selection.Contains(currentStartPosition))
            {
                DependencyObject element = currentStartPosition.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                if(element is TextBlock textBlock)
                {
                    text = textBlock.Text;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                parsingInProgress = false;
            }
        }
        break;

        case TextPointerContext.Text:
        {
            //we will parse 1 character at a time until we reach the end of the selection or an embedded element
            while (true)
            {
                //get the next character position
                var currentEndPosition = currentStartPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                if (richTextBox.Selection.Contains(currentEndPosition))
                {
                    var currentCharacterTextRange = new TextRange(currentStartPosition, currentEndPosition);
    
                    text                += currentCharacterTextRange.Text;
                    currentStartPosition = currentEndPosition;
    
                    //check if the next char exists or we reached content end
                    var nextToCurrentEndPosition = currentEndPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    if(nextToCurrentEndPosition == null)
                    {
                        parsingInProgress = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(!richTextBox.Selection.Contains(nextToCurrentEndPosition))
                    {
                        parsingInProgress = false;
                        break;
                    }
    
    
                    //check if next context is an embedded element
                    var tempContextStartPosition = currentEndPosition.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    if ((tempContextStartPosition == null))
                    {
                        parsingInProgress = false;
                        break;
                    }
    
                    //check if the next context is an embedded element
                    var tempContext = tempContextStartPosition.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    if (tempContext == TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement)
                    {
                        //stop parsing
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    parsingInProgress   = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    
    if (text != null)
    {
        _ = selectedTextBuilder.Append(text);
    }
    
    paragraph = currentStartPosition.Paragraph;
    if (!parsingInProgress)
        break;
    
    do
    {
        currentStartPosition = currentStartPosition.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        context              = currentStartPosition.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    } while ((context != TextPointerContext.Text) &&
              (context != TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement) &&
              (context != TextPointerContext.None));
}
    
var plainText = selectedTextBuilder.ToString().Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);

How to copy the runs and InlinUIContainer to be pasted again in the richtextBox

You can serialize the data into any data structure of your choice, in my case, I created a struct with Text and Alternate as members, and add this on every match to a list. 
On paste, Deserialize this data and insert at caret Position as run and InlinUIContainer

How to copy and paste into other apps like notepad
in the above code, copy the plaintext to clipboard which will do the job

You should avoid adding UIElement to the FLowDocument. The RichTextBox is already an extremely heavy and slow control. Adding UIElement objects significantly worsens the performance. Using a TextBlock to display text is redundant. Not only does it add layout related performance costs. It also eliminates efficiency when accessing the text of the document. For example, you could completely avoid the iteration of the document's elements if all text is presented using a lightweight Run.
The way you obtain the selected text is wrong. You are currently picking the complete Run instead of the selected portion:
string selectedText = RichTextBox.Selection.Text;

Then the iteration itself is also wrong and aside from being wrong extremely inefficient as you are iterating over the complete document instead of the selected portion. The circumstance that you are using a nested loop (foreach) makes the cost even worse.
You should use the text pointers to safely inspect the document or selection: This also avoids the nested loops as it enables you to linearly step through then document element by element based on the elements position in the document instead of the object hierarchy:
var selectedTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();

TextPointer contextPosition = this.RichTextBox.Selection.Start;
TextPointerContext context = contextPosition.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
Paragraph paragraph = contextPosition.Paragraph;

while (context is not TextPointerContext.None)
{
  // Append a line break if we are in the scope of a new Paragraph
  if (contextPosition.Paragraph != paragraph)
  {
    _ = selectedTextBuilder.AppendLine();
  }

  string text = null;
  switch (context)
  {
    case TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement:
      DependencyObject element = contextPosition.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);
      if (element is TextBlock textBlock)
      {
        text = textBlock.Text;
      }
      else if (element is TextBox textBox)
      {
        text = textBox.Text;
      }

      break;
    case TextPointerContext.Text:
      text = contextPosition.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
      break;
  }

  if (text is not null)
  {
    _ = selectedTextBuilder.Append(text);
  }

  paragraph = contextPosition.Paragraph;

  do
  {
    contextPosition = contextPosition.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    context = contextPosition.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
  } while (context 
      is not TextPointerContext.Text 
      and not TextPointerContext.EmbeddedElement 
      and not TextPointerContext.None);
}

string selectedText = selectedTextBuilder.ToString();


some context for why the inlineUIcontainer. In my richtextbox, i select a plaintext word "hello", i show a popup, where the user chooses to apply an alternate pronunciation to the selected word. so when i hover over this applied word, it shows a tooltip with example "hello -> helluv" , to achieve all this, inlinuiContainer was chosen. and now the user want to copy paste this applied word in other places of the richtextbox, and also managing the run in my use case is little tricky, example, if i modify the word "hello" to "he", i should also update the tooltip text "he -> helluv"

Ah, thanks for the context. I guess I would get the bounding box of the selected text and use it to show a Popup that aligns with this box. Could also imagine using an Adorner instead of the Popup. And why a RichTextBox?

Having a popup has nothing to do with the issue, that's a usability thing to show user other options, for the word here "hello" in different pronunciation style. what happens next is the thing. I am dealing with input box, where user types a sentence and can change the pronunciation of a particular word. I need to highlight this word in red and a custom tool tip to showcase that a alternate pronunciation is applied.

so when this whole data is sent to back end by parsing what is normal text and what is pronunciation text. What i did here is create  for normal text, and  for pronunciation text.

i have posted a modified version of your answer @BionicCode
